# How to check a path string string is a subfolder of a particular path

Tags: vbscript

I can have any number of source strings like listed below which I will be getting as arguments.

```
instring = 
"\\C:\Desktop\WORK\to\Archive\Abcv"
"\\C:\Desktop\WORK\to\Archive\dfrt"
"\\C:\Desktop\WORK\to\Archive"
"\\C:\Desktop\WORK\to\Archive\efgh"
```

I want to check if the folder name is `\\C:\Desktop\WORK\to\Archive` or if it is a folder inside the archive directory like `\\C:\Desktop\WORK\to\Archive\Abcv`.

To check if the string 'Archive' exists I can always use the `InStr()` function in VB scripting, but I want to check if some string exists after 'Archive' or not. i.e. if the argument which is passed is pointing to 'Archive' folder or a folder inside it.

Comment: [Check](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954(v=vs.84).aspx) `Replace( instring, "C:\Desktop\WORK\to\Archive", "", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the archive path from your string and check if the remaining string has a length greater than zero.

```
instring = "\\C:\Desktop\WORK\to\Archive\dfrt"

archiveDir = "\\C:\Desktop\WORK\to\Archive"

If Len(Replace(instring, archiveDir, "", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)) > 0 Then
  WScript.Echo instring & " is a subfolder of " & archiveDir & "."
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs !! I am looking for a feature in VB script where we can see if there is some string existing after a specified string like we do in Oracle statemensts : Like col1 = '\Archive\%'

Comment: VBScript doesn't have wildcard matches for strings. You can the method described above, you can use `InStr`, or you can use regular expressions.